# Trimming output

Tags: powershell, trim

I would like to be able to reduce the output from my script and then if possible to query the End Code to write to the user if the End Code is correct.

This is the code im currently using:

```
foreach ($line in $contentt) {
  Write-Host $line -BackgroundColor DarkGray -ForegroundColor Black

  $date = Get-Date -format "MMM dd"
  $yday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MMM dd")
  $output  = Get-Content -Path "$line" |
             Select-String -Pattern $date -SimpleMatch |
             Select-String -Pattern "End Code" 
  $youtput = Get-Content -Path "$line" |
             Select-String -Pattern $yday -SimpleMatch |
             Select-String -Pattern "End Code"
  if ($output -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "No content in the file for today"
  } else {
    Write-Host $output
  }
  if ($youtput -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "No content in the file for yesterday"
  } else {
    Write-Host $youtput
  }
}
```

This is the output im currently receiving:

```
Jan 26, 2015 7:34:37 AM JobName  - ID  = 15 , End Code   = 0 , time (ms)  = 2046
```

I would like to be able to trim the output to be:

```
EndCode = 0
```

Comment: if the commas are placed consistantly maybe just split.  .split(",")[2]

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is a mix of Substring() and IndexOf():

```
$a = "Jan 26, 2015 7:34:37 AM JobName - ID = 15 , End Code = 0 , time (ms) = 2046"
$a.Substring($a.IndexOf("End"),$a.IndexOf(" , time") - $a.IndexOf("End"))
```

It produces `End Code = 0`

Comment: It wont let me use this in the script as it states that "IndexOf : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." this would be the $output and $youtput, the value is null as I am using "| select-string" as far as I can tell.

Comment: Not sure, if i understand correctly, but you are already checking, if there is $null inside $output or $youtput. Both variables are already string ....
What does it tells you, if you try $Output.get-type() ? should be string, and so, the indexof() method should apply (assuming, the var isnt $null).

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression replacement:

```
$output -replace '.*(End Code = \d+).*', '$1'
```

or, since you're already using `Select-String`:

```
... | Select-String -Pattern '(End Code = \d+)' | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Matches.Groups[0].Value
}
```

If the string contains multiple spaces before and/or after the `=` change the grouped expression to `(End Code += +\d+)`.